# Why is cin.failbit always set even when input is valid?

Tags: c++, arrays, cin, getline

I was trying to write a program that asks to input a char array using `cin.getline()` and if given input is bigger than array length array gets extended.

I used `cin.failbit` to see if user's input was too long. But nothing went right. So after debugging I figured out that the problem lies in `failbit`.

So I wrote a simple program to see what was wrong about it and it turned out that somehow `cin.failbit` ***always*** returns true when in if-statement even when input seems valid.

```
int main () {
    char name[256];

    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::cin.getline (name,256, '\n');

    std::cout << "characters read: " << std::cin.gcount() << std::endl;
    if (std::cin.failbit){
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cout << "failed\n";
    }
}
```

For example, when input is "qwer" program outputs that 5 characters have been read (`cin.gcount`), so it should be fine but it also outputs "fail" meaning that failbit flag is set. But I believe it shouldn't be in this case.

[program output here](https://ideone.com/e10r5N)

So can anyone explain why `failbit` appears to be set permanently?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: @fran please answer in answer not comments.

Comment: FWIW you can use `if (!std::cin)` instead to check if the stream is in a failure state.

Comment: I was mistaken, there is no `failbit` member function. It's checking that the value of the [failbit bit mask](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) isn't zero. I was thinking of the `fail()` member function. `std::cin.failbit` is a constant that indicates which bit represents a failed state, it's not checking the state of the stream.

Comment: thanks for replies. I considered using cin.fail() or !cin but they are not invoked when user's input is longer than the len of the array. User's input just gets cut and all characters past the size of array remain in the buffer (at least that is what I observed)

Comment: @keptt That's because you are asking for `255` characters, and it succeeded in giving you those characters. It's not an error to still have data in the input buffer after reading from it. The easy solution would be to just read into a `std::string`.

Comment: also shouldn't failbit be a flag that gets set in certain conditions according to cppref (I was reading about cin.getline)? Guess I'll check it again, but I still don't quite get  the situation described in my question

Comment: and I'm sorry but for my assignment only char arrays are permitted. That's why I seek for the way of doing it like above in my question or so

Comment: @keptt No, `failbit` is *not* a flag in the stateful sense. It indicates which bit is associated with that flag. It cannot be set or cleared, it's a constant. The phrase "the `failbit` flag" means "the bit indicated by the bitmask `failbit`".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::cin.failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is a constant that indicates which of the error bits represents stream failure. It is not an indication of the stream's current state. To check if that bit is set, use the member function [`std::cin.fail()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) instead.

However, if the stream failed to read due to reaching the end of the stream `fail()` will return `false` leading you to believe that it succeeded. Prefer [`std::cin.good()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) to check if the last operation succeeded.

Comment: [Documentation link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate)

Comment: I appreciate the answer but for me the part about failbit just interferes with getline description [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) 4th block here states: "The failbit flag is set if the function extracts no characters, or if the delimiting character is not found once (n-1) characters have already been written to s". So for me it's confusing

Comment: @keptt The error state is stored in a bitset. `failbit` is a constant that indicates which of the bits represents failure. For example, it's value might be the constant `8` indicating that the 4th bit indicates failure. In that instance, your `if` would be essentially `if(8)` and doesn't account for the current state of your stream. An example of a use for `failbit` might be `std::cin.rdstate() & std::ios_base::failbit` to see if the `failbit` is `1` in the bitset returned by `rdstate()`.

Comment: thanks, I guess I get it now. I tried to act on your advise and used cin.good() - it worked just fine so far. Not to be too annoying but would you mind me asking about dealing with failbit? If it's a constant then it should have some kind of default value meaning if I type smth like - if(cin.failbit == default_value) it would mean that no errors that can trigger failbit were detected and everything is fine. Is it like that?

Comment: @keptt No. `failbit` has nothing to do with `cin`'s state. Imagine it's a global constant (because that's what it is). There is no useful information you can extract from it, it's a number and it's always that number for the lifetime of your program. Imagine everywhere you see `failbit` that it instead just says `4`, or `16` or whatever value it has. It cannot change during the lifetime of your program. It's *only* use is as a bitmask to help you interpret the value returned by `rdstate()`. The fact that `std::cin.failbit` compiles is misleading. `failbit` is a `static constexpr`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Your answers were of great help. It took me long enough but as I finally assumed failbit indicates a bit that represents a failure in a bitset that in turn represents a stream state (as you already said). When it was stated in cppreference that getline sets failbit flag, I surmise it meant something lilke "it changes a certain bit indicated by failbit constant in the bitset, so that afterwards functions like cin.fail() or cin.good() could get the proper information on current stream state"